# Draw a separator line on UIView in Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard, line, draw

I am trying to draw a straight separator line on an UIView. Basically, this is not so hard but I was wondering if there exists an easier way to do this. For example in the Storyboard.

Actually, I am drawing the line using a self created UIView with 1px height and a certain background color.

What I want to do is something like in Apple's Mail App: (the separator line)

(Sorry for the huge image - is there a way to set the size in this editor?)

[image: apple mail app]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to use a static UITableView. You can set it on storyboard and use your custom cells, and the tableView will create that separator lines. I would create each cell from storyboard.

Comment: Doesn't always help. What if I want a static table and do not want to use the UITableViewController?